# How can I read Firebase Documentation

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

How can I read Firebase Documentation to help build my flutter application As I know only dart programming language and the documentation guides are given in all other languages except dart? In their documentation guides they have given a separate syntax section to implement the given concept, In which I was able to grasp the code syntax from their web and java section (as I don't know why but it was very similar to dart),but still the exact syntax for my dart and flutter is not given what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) help? It is the documentation for flutter and firebase with examples in dart language.

Comment: Yeah for starting it's okay but for doing more complex things which obviously is required for building a full fledged App,more extensive documentation will be required,that is the issue!! (hope some google folk see this and come to my rescue :D)